# Are there in android vars or constants with colors of color sceme?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, color-scheme

Other languages I used to use some constants that named something like "BackgroundColor" or "TextColor". If I want to color my component I just set its color using that constants, and I didn't care what color it was in particular.

For example, I set some color to ColorText and when user changed main color sceme my component will be visible for sure and color will suit this color sceme. And if I will set my color to just Black there may be a circumstance when it just will not be visible.

Is there a color-constants that change inside for different color scemes in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no one `BackgroundColor` for all etc. But you can get the same effect by using styles and themes. Please developer docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and example tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)

Comment: but is there somewhere style.xml that paint holo light fro example?

Comment: Yes. you got platform themes/styles in `SDK/platform/android-X/data/res` folder